# How to prevent Scan from running multiple times?

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

For example

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
var test = subject.Scan(0, (x, y) => {
    Console.WriteLine("scan");
    return x + 1;
});
test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe1"));
//test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe2"));
Observable.Range(0, 1).Subscribe(subject);
Console.WriteLine("done");
Console.Read();
```

The output is

```
scan
subscribe1
done
```

But if you uncomment second Subscribe the output is

```
scan
subscribe1
scan
subscribe2
done
```

Why does the Scan run two times and how can I prevent it?
So output should be

```
scan
subscribe1
subscribe2
done
```

I use Subject to accumulate different Observables. Then I use Scan method to update Model and then I have different places where I need to subscribe to Model updates. Maybe is there better solution without using Subject?

Comment: Do you understand that observables are a "promise" to execute a pipeline **only** when they are subscribed to? So `test` isn't executed once, it is executed each time you subscribe. So hence the two runs of `Scan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`Observable.Publish`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229126(v=vs.103).aspx) to get an `IConnectableObservable<T>`.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
var test = subject
    .Scan(0, (x, y) => {
        Console.WriteLine("scan");
        return x + 1;
    })
    .Publish();
test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe1"));
test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe2"));
test.Connect();
Observable.Range(0, 1).Subscribe(subject);
Console.WriteLine("done");
Console.Read();
```

Output:

```
scan
subscribe1
subscribe2
done
```

`Publish` turns the cold `Scan` observable into a hot observable that begins emitting values when `Connect` is called.

Comment: Why cannot I just connect right after publish .....Publish(); test.Connect(); What is the difference?

Comment: @ais You can just call it after `Publish`.  It wouldn't make sense to call `Connect` multiple times, however.

Comment: The difference is that once you call `Connect`, test will begin publishing values immediately. If you want all the subscribers to get the values you need to wait until they are subscribed before `Connect`ing

Comment: @paulpdaniels The subject doesn't produce any values until the third-from-last line.

Comment: @Timothy, ah good point, take my comment as a general note on side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is that `Subject` is a hot observable while `Scan` creates a new cold observable every time you subscribe to it.

Try moving scan before the subject instead

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe1"));
subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe2"));
Observable.Range(0, 1).Scan(0, (x, y) => {
    Console.WriteLine("scan");
    return x + 1;
}).Subscribe(subject);
Console.WriteLine("done");
Console.Read();
```

You can also do it without the `Subject`:

```
var test = Observable.Range(0, 1).Scan(0, (x, y) => {
    Console.WriteLine("scan");
    return x + 1;
}).Publish();

test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe1"));
test.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("subscribe2"));
test.Connect();

Console.WriteLine("done");
Console.Read();
```

[Hot vs Cold Observables](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx)

Comment: But I need to create new subscribers after I define Scan. Also I need Subject to accumulate different Observables in runtime. What can I do?

Comment: I have added an overall description of the problem

Comment: You can use `Merge` in place of the `Subject` but the problem is still hot vs cold.  You need to stick one of the `Multicast` family (`Publish`, `Replay` or `PublishValue`) in order to convert `Scan` into a hot observable.

Comment: @paulpdaniels - `.Scan` doesn't create cold observables. If the source was hot then it remains hot.